# Specify driver for given device?

Tags: wifi, drivers, kernel-modules

I have an interesting problem. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 (distro: elementary OS Freya).

I have a MacBook Pro in a dock which provides ethernet over USB 3. The USB ethernet device id is `0b95:1790` and uses `wl` for the driver via the `linux-firmware` and `bcmwl-kernel-source` package. It seems to be working fine, though before it was in gigabit mode and now it seems to be running in 100 megabit mode; no big deal, it works.

The problem is with my wireless card, which has an id of `14e4:43ba`. According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639198/macbook-11-5-wifi-14e443ba-doesnt-work-on-14-04), I need to uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` in order to allow the wireless card to start working. This means that the `wl` module will be removed from the kernel and I'll lose access to ethernet. While I prefer ethernet, I would like to be able to move around with my laptop without running from cable to cable.

I need the ethernet device to use `wl`, but I need `wl` to ignore my wireless card and have that card be handled by the `brcmfmac` driver, as per the thread above. How can I do this?

Comment: I was able to work around the issue by getting rid of `wl` altogether using a company-provided kernel module driver, but that doesn't answer my OP.